# Use Javascript array as Ajax source in Datatables

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I have a Javascript Array that outputs:

> [Object { component1 ="method"}, Object { component2="method3"},
>   Object {  component3="method5"}]

upon `console.log()` in `Firebug`

How can I use this to populate a `DataTables` table using the `sAjaxDataSource` option?

Comment: Why would you? There's no ajax needed when you have the data already. Look at the [array data source](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Comment: I've never seen an array being logged like that. Did you manually add the `Object`s, spaces and `=`?

Comment: @Bergi True,  I have the data already, but the way the data is, , not sure I can use that. How do i format it to suit the format in the link(thanks for that)?

Comment: @Broxzier I have a wizard interface, at each step of the wizard, is a group of radio buttons, upon clicking a radio button in the last group of radio buttons-2nd last step of wizard, I loop through the checked radios, and push each into the array. That's how. Kinda manual

Comment: @Broxzier Working hard to put it up on JSFiddle.